# Converting a saved tensorflow model to IR using openvino model optimizer

Tags: tensorflow, openvino

I trained a custom CNN model using keras and tensorflow 2.2.0 as background. After that, I saved the model as .ckpt file having assets, variables, .pb file as subfolders init. After that to convert it into IR in openvino documentation it is given that we have use the following command:

**To convert such TensorFlow model:
Go to the <INSTALL_DIR>/deployment_tools/model_optimizer directory

Run the mo_tf.py script with a path to the SavedModel directory to convert a model:

python3 mo_tf.py --saved_model_dir <SAVED_MODEL_DIRECTORY>**

so, I went to the following directory as mentioned and tired the following command:

**python3 mo_tf.py --saved_model_dir C:\Users\vyas\Desktop\saved_model\cp.ckpt**

There is no output or anything. There is no error also.
Also, I tried the following command:

**python3 mo_tf.py --saved_model_dir C:\Users\vyas\Desktop\saved_model\cp.ckpt --output_dir C:\Users\vyas\Desktop\out**

Still there is no output.

Can someone please help.

**I am using tensorflow 2.2.0**

Can someone please help me with this

Answer (score 2):

--saved_model_dir must provide a path to the SavedModel directory.

Modify your command as follows:

python3 mo_tf.py --saved_model_dir C:\Users\vyas\Desktop\saved_model